# Please why does this work when client_id is empty here

Tags: authorization, auth0, auth0-connection, auth0-js

Hello im new to auth0 and i want to know  why is this working:
im making a post request to /dbconnections/signup with this body :

```
{
  "client_id" : "CLIENT_ID",
  "email" : "myemail",
  "username" : "myuser",
  "password" : "mypass",
  "connection" : "Username-Password-Authentication"
}
```

this returns “connection is disabled” because i have it disabled for the client but for some reason when i leave the client_id empty it says the account is created :

```
{
  "client_id" : "id_generated",
  "email_verified" : false,
  "email" : "myemail"
}
```

thanks

why does it work when client_id is empty

Comment: you're providing an appendage of an animal and want us to guess it's an elephant, '/dbconnections/signup' is your api?  and "client_id" : "id_generated", is generated by a custom application that returns 'id_generated' based on what, user exist in a database. What you've provided is not sufficient to help you.

Comment: im sorry like i said im very new to this ,i do not have access to auth dashboard so i cant answer your questions , maybe my question should be is it possible to have empty client id

Comment: The "client_id" is an identifier that uniquely identifies the application and is issue by the identity provider when the application is registered to Identity provider. When the user, uses the application to access a resource that's "protected" (need authentication for access), the client_id & client_secret is required to be passed in the request, see diagram https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2. Shouldn't work with an empty client_id.

Comment: This Microsoft site has a more detail (possibly confusing) diagram, but contains terms that you can search by to further your understanding of OAuth (hope all this somewhat helps).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2

Comment: `client_id` is auto-generated from the Auth0 side. Therefore, no need to define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i asked the same question on the auth forum and the reason why is this working is because apparently `client_id`  is not actually required for the /dbconnections/signup endpoint despite what the documentation said: https://community.auth0.com/t/please-why-does-this-work-when-client-id-is-empty-here/96211